# Count the most frequent value and manipulate it

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follow:

```
            User           Bought 

0           U296             PC
1           U300            Table
2           U296             PC
3           U296            Chair
```

I would like to create 2 columns, one displays the most bought item for a user and the second displays the number of times this item is been bought so I get at the end:

```
            User           Bought         Most_Bought          Times_bought

0           U296             PC               PC                    2
1           U300            Table            Table                  1
2           U296             PC               PC                    2
3           U296            Chair             PC                    2
```

I know that I should do something like a groupby and make use of mode() but I'm missing the final touch.

Thank you for help !

Comment: It would be a pain to add a single row of data to such a DataFrame. Does this all need to reside in a single data structure?  Why not a second DataFrame for this type of reporting statistic? I'm sure what you ask is easy for someone who knows `pandas`, but what sticks out to me is that it looks like bad data design.

Comment: Show how you did this in its non-final form then.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [330]: g = df.groupby('User')['Bought']

In [331]: vc = g.value_counts().to_frame(name='Times_bought').reset_index()

In [332]: df = df.merge(vc)

In [333]: df
Out[333]:
   User Bought  Times_bought Most_Bought
0  U296     PC             2          PC
1  U296     PC             2          PC
2  U300  Table             1       Table
3  U296  Chair             1          PC

In [334]: df['Most_Bought'] = df['User'].map(g.agg(lambda x: x.mode()[0]))

In [335]: df
Out[335]:
   User Bought  Times_bought Most_Bought
0  U296     PC             2          PC
1  U296     PC             2          PC
2  U300  Table             1       Table
3  U296  Chair             1          PC
```

---

**Old answer:**

[IIUC](https://www.acronymfinder.com/If-I-Understand-Correctly-(IIUC).html):

```
In [222]: x = df.groupby('User')['Bought'] \
     ...:       .agg([lambda x: x.mode()[0], 'nunique']) \
     ...:       .rename(columns={'<lambda>':'Most_Bought','nunique':'Times_bought'})
     ...:

In [223]: df.merge(x, left_on='User', right_index=True)
Out[223]:
   User Bought Most_Bought  Times_bought
0  U296     PC          PC             2
2  U296     PC          PC             2
3  U296  Chair          PC             2
1  U300  Table       Table             1
```

preserving original order:

```
In [258]: df.merge(x, left_on='User', right_index=True).reindex(df.index)
Out[258]:
   User Bought Most_Bought  Times_bought
0  U296     PC          PC             2
1  U300  Table       Table             1
2  U296     PC          PC             2
3  U296  Chair          PC             2
```

Helper DF:

```
In [224]: x
Out[224]:
     Most_Bought  Times_bought
User
U296          PC             2
U300       Table             1
```

Comment: This is the second time I have seen IIUC today. Finally had to look it up.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, yeah, i'm trying to save time on such phrases... :-)

Comment: I'm testing it, but btw what is IIUC ?

Comment: @hdatas, [IIUC](https://www.acronymfinder.com/If-I-Understand-Correctly-(IIUC).html) ;-)

Comment: @MaxU haha you need to add `ELSE` part too to that `IF` ;)

Comment: My favorite time-saving phrase to type is Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V :)

Comment: @Divakar, yeah, it would be pretty hard to add an ELSE part in this case :-D

Comment: Should I replace nunique in the code with 'Times_bought' ? after lambda

Comment: add a new method , if you are interested :)

Comment: Learn new thing dude, first time saw lambda combine self function and build in function!

Comment: It's working but for one thing, the indexes are mixed up, how can I sort it again without changing the order ? simple reset_index ?

Comment: @hdatas `df.sort_index()`

Comment: @Wen, what do you mean?

Comment: @Wen I need to bring back old indexed cuz this df is originally a set of 2 and after I do this manipulation, I would like to split them back. Does the sort_index bring it back ?

Comment: @hdatas, `df.merge(x, left_on='User', right_index=True).reindex(df.index)` - i've added it to the answer...

Comment: let us change the 'Chair' to `PC`, nunique give back 1  , should it be 3 ?

Comment: @hdatas, i'd go with Wen's solution. I'll try to fix mine when i'll have bit more time...

Comment: @MaxU Guys Wen's seems more accurate but is crashing my pc cuz I have big data and yours needs to be fixed but the job can be done :P

Answer (score 2):

Take me long time to make it came true :) By using `value_counts`

```
df[['Most_Bought','Times_bought']]=df.groupby('User').Bought.transform(lambda x : [pd.Series(x).value_counts()\
                             .reset_index().loc[0].values]).apply(pd.Series)
df
Out[231]: 
   User Bought Most_Bought  Times_bought
0  U296     PC          PC             2
1  U300  Table       Table             1
2  U296     PC          PC             2
3  U296  Chair          PC             2
```

Comment: That's interesting! I've also started with `.transform`, but i gave up... :-)

Comment: @MaxU the solution come into my mind is like yours ,and I am thinking how to make it one step:)

Comment: Yeah I bet pandas folks are crazy about one-liners :)

Comment: Still running your method, it's taking it's time :P

Comment: Is it possible to separate or do something in order to consume less ram ? I've got like 3 million rows and ram went to 100% :P

Comment: @hdatas let us waiting for MaxU. his method should be quicker